# Recursion Error when Modifying ManyToManyField during Django Model Save

Tags: python, django

I have an issue with removing users from the `friends` field during save in Django.

Here's a description of my idea:

Each Profile has a `type`, which corresponds to a certain rank. For instance, a Profile with `type` X can have 10 friends, whereas a Profile with type Y can have 20 friends.

Here's how I've implemented it:

```py
POWER_OF_PROFILE_TYPE = {"X": 0, "Y": 1}

class ProfileType(models.TextChoices):
    X = "X", "x"
    Y = "Y", "y"

class Profile(models.Model):
    type = models.TextField(choices=ProfileType.choices, default=ProfileType.BASIC, max_length=1)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name="friends")
    __currently_type = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__currently_type = self.type_of_profile

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        if self.type_of_profile != self.__currently_type:
            if POWER_OF_PROFILE_TYPE[self.type_of_profile] < POWER_OF_PROFILE_TYPE[self.__currently_type]:
                users = self.friends.all()[10:]
                self.friends.remove(*users)
                self.save()  # This is causing recursion error

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__currently_type = self.type_of_profile
```

Unfortunately, this piece of code results in a recursion error `RecursionError ...maximum recursion depth exceeded`
Could someone help me figure out what I should do?

Comment: can you provide the full stacktrace please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to call `.save()` after call `.remove()` on M2M fields.

Remove the line causing error and you should be fine.

Comment: It's a great answer ;) But there;s one problem: when I use `.save()` in the shell it deletes users. However,  when I edit the type in the admin site and press save, the type changes  but users aren't deleted. Do you know why?

Comment: @Mateusz: because the m2m field is saved *after* it saved the object, so yes, the items are removed, but then restored back when saving the many-to-many field. But it also looks quite strange what you are trying to achieve. If you "lose" power, you lose the first (whatever that is) ten friends?

Comment: @willem-van-onsem That's right. The `type` field is a subscription level indicator. If  a user's  `type` is set to 'Y', they have access to additional features. However, if the user doesn't extend their subscription, their `type` is changed to basic ('X' in my case), resulting in the loss of benefits such as the no. of friends they can have. Therefore, I must reduce the number of friends (whatever that it)